# Ubuntu 18.10 Keyboard Doesn't Work - Corsair K70 RGB Rapidfire

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, ubiquity

I'm trying to use Ubuntu 18.10 Cosmic Cuttlefish. However, when I boot the installer, my keyboard does not work. My keyboard is a Corsair K70 RGB Rapidfire. Either the default red lights will turn on, or nothing will turn on at all. This does not happen to my mouse, however. This problem does not occur in BIOS, GRUB, Windows, and any other distros running 4.18. Something weird to note is that if I were to use proprietary NVIDIA drivers, then the chance of my keyboard working on boot drops significantly. The only distro I've had 100% success on keyboard boots is Arch running 4.18, with nouveau drivers. This doesn't seem to have any relation to the keyboard drivers, but I'm not exactly sure. I've contacted the maintainer of linux-input, and he is not sure either. This problem is occuring on Ubiquity, and Ubiquity seems to fail more than the actual installed OS. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** I've tried out ckb-next, and while it does give my keyboard extra RGB options, it sadly does not fix the driver issues.